# Using data from .CSV with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have an .csv file that looks like:

```
 oS,browName,browVer,timeCanvas,timeSvg
 Windows,Firefox,25.0,0.25,1.23
 Windows,Opera,12.16,0.572,1.465
```

And i would like to do a function that will count arithmetic mean for timeCanvas and timeSvg looking something like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < maxrow; i++)
{
 if(oS=Windows)
 {
  if(browName=FireFox
   {
     if(browVer=25.0)
      {
       a=a+1;
       timeC=timeC+timeCanvas
       timeS=timeS+timeSvg
      }
     }
    }
   ...
 }
```

I googled my problem and only solution i could find was jquery-csv 0.7 with toObjects method (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/)> I would like to know is it possible with this libaarry to do what i want?? And if there are some good examples (couldnt find myself)??

..........................................................................

Edit:

so i tryed vadim solution but it deos not working and i dont know hwat i do worng.Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function draw(){

var a = 0,
    timeC = 0,
    timeS = 0,
meanCFf=0,
meanSFf= 0;

$.get('test1.csv').done(function(data) {
var i, 
    lines = data.split('\n'),
    line = lines[0].split(','),
    oS = line.indexOf('oS'),
    browName = line.indexOf('browName'),
    browVer = line.indexOf('browVer'),
    timeCanvas = line.indexOf('timeCanvas'),
    timeSvg = line.indexOf('timeSvg'); 
for(i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i].split(',');
    if(line[oS] === 'Windows') {
        a++;
        timeC += parseFloat(line[timeCanvas], 10);
        timeS += parseFloat(line[timeSvg], 10);
    }
}
});
    meanCFf = timeC/a;
meanSFf = timeC/a;
var os1 = document.getElementById("osInfo1");
os1.innerHTML = "Twoja średnia  to: " + meanCFf;
var os2 = document.getElementById("osInfo2");
os2.innerHTML = "Twój sytem operacyjny to: " + meanSFf;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
    <p id="osInfo1"></p>
    <p id="osInfo2"></p>
</body>
```

It looks like for loop is not working coz a is zero all the time.

Comment: First, get your csv file with `$.ajax()` and then use this lib.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens. Go try it and see if something breaks. Then come back here and tell us the error. There are examples on the homepage of the link that you gave us.

Comment: You got some errors in your code: missing `)` and `=` where you should have `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

**JavaScript (script.js)**

```
$(function() {
  var a = 0,
      timeC = 0,
      timeS = 0;
  $.get('test1.csv').done(function(data) {
      var i, 
          lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/),
          line = lines[0].split(','),
          oS = line.indexOf('oS'),
          browName = line.indexOf('browName'),
          browVer = line.indexOf('browVer'),
          timeCanvas = line.indexOf('timeCanvas'),
          timeSvg = line.indexOf('timeSvg');
      for(i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
          line = lines[i].split(',');
          if(line[oS] === 'Windows' && line[browName] === 'Firefox' && line[browVer] === '25.0') {
              a++;
              timeC += parseFloat(line[timeCanvas], 10);
              timeS += parseFloat(line[timeSvg], 10);
          }
      }

      $('#osInfo1').html("Twoja średnia  to: " + timeC/a);
      $('#osInfo2').html("Twój sytem operacyjny to: " + timeS/a);
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>CSV Test</h1>
    <div id="osInfo1"></div>
    <div id="osInfo2"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wanted to try your solution but i cant get it to work. I edited post and pasted my code mybe i do something wrong

Comment: @user3022030 You are trying to use `timeC` and `timeS`  before you calculate them. `$.get()` is asynchronous and you can use values calculated based on response in `.done(function{...})` callback only; `FireFox` and `Firefox` are different strings; If csv file was created on Windows environment than line breaks will be `\r\n` instead of `\n`. I've edited my post with all these features. Here is working example  http://plnkr.co/edit/mAaIGICzszPPX6g78mMe?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could get the folder manually with javascript and then attempt to manually parse it OR you could use PHP.
PHP has some great libraries for working with CSV which come standard.

Rather than go through all the effort of working with it manually every time I would personally create a simply PHP JSON service which carries out the function you require of the csv simply and delivers the data. You can then retrieve you the data using Javascript AJAX allowing you perform the code you need as usual.

Overall, I think you'll find this will mean less code for you and theres a lot more documentation on the net to support both the PHP CSV and the JSON service.

Of course, this is assuming that you have a server that has PHP.